# The button in between two checkboxes

Tags: discussion, design

This has always bothered me on the SE sites.
There's two checkboxes and in between there is a button.
Something about this design really bothers me.  It's cluttered seems like there are too many actions (hyperlinks 3, with 2 checkboxes, with 1 button, all on three lines).  All in all its visually not appealing because you have a line of text that is long, a button that is not as long, and then yet another line of text that is long.  **It is not right period and you designers no it isn't right.**

[image]

I can understand why you want the "**Send me new responses to my posts via email**" checkbox needing to come before "**Posting Your Question**" since logically you want someone to check or uncheck this before posting their own question.  But I **hate** that "**Answer your own question**" is right after it.  First of all it shouldn't even be a checkbox...checkboxes are not used for things like this.  Can we change this to a hyperlink that actually shows the content...

Something like this:

[image]

And if you do click `or answer your own question` its as simple as this:

[image]

I think I've mentioned this in the past but it fell off the face of the earth.  Can a designer from SO/SE please give the reasons why it looks the way it looks.  It just currently looks odd, disgusting, messed up, cluttered, **insert angry word here...**.

Comment: A C++ embedded device engineer downvoted me.

Comment: Why do you understand *why you want the "Send me new responses to my posts via email" checkbox needing to come before "Posting Your Question"* because I don't. In my logic that checkbox could come last and still make sense.

Comment: rene I'm not saying I like that part either...what I am saying is from a workflow perspective that is fine because you want to set that before you post your question so its logical to show that first before the button.  Yes I still think that is ugly too.

Comment: *checkboxes are not used for things like this.* It's very common to show/hide additional fields based on a checkbox being ticked or not.

Comment: Glorfindel thats true if those checkboxes' state has some sort of meaning or is saved.  But for something like visibility, which all this is doing, a link is more appropriate IMHO.

Comment: The classically (outdated) anchor-styled link implies navigation not dynamic interaction. I don't think this would be an improvement, and in my opinion looks worse.

Comment: An outdated anchor...boy o boy...I thought i heard them all...now all anchors are outdated.  Anchor smanker...

Comment: No, not all anchors, just the `color:blue; text-decoration: underline;` style (**outdated**) which is shown. For example, there is not one blue underlined link anywhere on this page, nor on the ask question page, the front page of main, etc..

Comment: @TravisJ - That is balsamiq mockups please don't take my colors and style as being a final version.  My point is to use a hyperlink and a clean up of the design - let the designers pick and choose the colors.  My version of balsamiq `color:blue; text-deocoration:underline;` cannot be changed in balsamiq.  I am only using it as an example...My post is not about please use blue as an anchor style element, no my post is how we should clean this up.